# plist in Index.html using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, plist

Can I read a plist file in my index.HTML? Actually I want to add multiple links with which application will interact, and I want those links to be in a plist. Is there any way to retrieve them in HTML file?

please help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the file is in the `www` folder, you could parse it using an XML parser, or even a specialty plist parser such as this: https://github.com/pugetive/plist_parser

If you are looking to have the file outside the `www` folder you might also need to use PhoneGap's File API to get the contents of the file.

Comment: hmmm... can i store value in local storage while application is at phase webViewDidFinishLoad? or some area from where i can retrive that value from html page

Comment: Thanks your solution works... but there is minor prob... it also read the commented tags